# Aspose formula detection

Tags: java, excel, aspose

I am trying to create placeholders for fields in excel using aspose.cells for java. I know about smartmarkers. The user uses <> to specify placeholders and I would process that to then change it to the '&=' notation. How would I do this for formulae. If I have some formula in <> does aspose have functions to detect if given key is a formula?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to use Find or Search options (via Aspose.Cells APIs) to first detect/find if a cell has your desired given key, e.g a string starts with "<>" (please see the [document](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Find+or+Search+Data) for your reference), then you would use or replace it with dynamic/repeat dynamic formula as: 
1) "&==DynamicFormula" -> Dynamic formula, example: &==A{r}*B{r}
2) "&=&=RepeatDynamicFormula" --> Repeat Dynamic formula, example which would be placed/repeated in each row, example: &=&=A{r}*B{r}. 
(Please see the [document](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Using+Smart+Markers) for your reference).

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: "<>" may also have column headers. I want to know if I can call an inbuilt function that can tell me if what is enclosed in "<>" is a formula

Comment: Well, there is no such built-in function. I think you got to use Find/Search options provided by Aspose.Cells and evaluate if it is formula or not. In MS  Excel a formula generally starts with "=" character.